# (A cube with labeled vertices) How to draw a cube with a letter written on each of the vertices, and the invisibible edges are marked as dotted lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, 3d, tikz-3d

Please edit for suitable tags, if you know some related tag.

See the **3rd page** of [this paper by Bhargava](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n1-p03.pdf).
There is a cube drawn there, which you can see in the image below (everything is black and white there, of course):

[image]

[image]

Notice that in this cube, a letter is written on each of the vertices.

I want to draw a cube where **the invisible edges are marked with dotted lines (=dashed dots)**, and at the point of intersection with the visible edges, these edges are completely invisible from a small distance before and after (and not as a dotted line), like the 2nd and 4th images. And I need to emphasize that I cannot draw any of the pictures in this question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And besides the dotted lines, is it possible to put a sphere in the vertices? Like the picture below:

[image]

[image]

I've seen suggestions in [this question (What is the easiest way to draw a 3D cube with TikZ?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-a-3d-cube-with-tikz), and also [this question (How may I put labels on the corners/vertices of a cube?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270226/how-may-i-put-labels-on-the-corners-vertices-of-a-cube), and also [this question (How can I draw a graph that looks like this hand drawn picture?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593419/how-can-i-draw-a-graph-that-looks-like-this-hand-drawn-picture), but they are not what I am looking for.

---

---

Using the codes presented in [the answer by Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692094/bhargava-cube-how-to-draw-a-cube-with-a-letter-written-on-each-of-the-vertices/692100#692100), I tried to create the 2nd and the 5th cube, but it seems that I don't know how to use the **`crossing over` command**. **Also, I don't know how to remove the circles**.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzcdset{3d cd/.style={/tikz/every odd row/.append style={xshift={#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  3d cd=2em, arrows=dash, row sep=.6em, column sep=1.5em,
  dedo/.style={dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 2\pgflinewidth},% custom dashes
  cells={nodes={
      circle, draw, inner sep=+.2em, % make all nodes the same size:
      align=center, text width=width("$f$"), text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em,
      t/.style={text={####1}}}}]
   |[t=yellow]| c_1 \ar[r]        \ar[d]
 & |[t=green]|  d_1 \ar[dd]       \ar[d]                          \\
   |[t=green]|  a_1 \ar[dd]       \ar[r, crossing over]
 & |[t=purple]| b_1 \ar[dd, crossing over]                                       \\
   |[t=red]|    c_2 \ar[d, dedo] \ar[r, dedo] \ar[uu, dedo]
 & |[t=yellow]| d_2 \ar[d]                                              \\
   |[t=yellow]| a_2 \ar[r]
 & |[t=green]|  b_2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369652/how-to-label-the-faces-of-a-commutative-cube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzcdset{3d cd/.style={/tikz/every odd row/.append style={xshift={#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  3d cd=2em, arrows=dash, row sep=.6em, column sep=1.5em,
  dedo/.style={dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 2\pgflinewidth},% custom dashes
  cells={nodes={
      circle, draw, inner sep=+.2em, % make all nodes the same size:
      align=center, text width=width("$f$"), text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em,
      t/.style={text={####1}}}}]
   |[t=yellow]| e \ar[r]        \ar[d]
 & |[t=green]|  b \ar[dd]       \ar[d, dedo]                          \\
   |[t=green]|  e \ar[dd]       \ar[r, dedo]
 & |[t=purple]| f \ar[dd, dedo]                                       \\
   |[t=red]|    c \ar[d] \ar[r, crossing over] \ar[uu, crossing over]
 & |[t=yellow]| d \ar[d]                                              \\
   |[t=yellow]| g \ar[r]
 & |[t=green]|  h
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

When I copy your code into an empty file, I can get the output (although it's probably too big, and I need to resize it).

Unfortunately, I don't know too much about LaTeX, and I can't get output from this code when I use the `\input` command.

Comment: Using your codes, I tried to create the 2nd cube, but it seems that I don't know how to use the **`crossing over` command** (I added the image of the output and this comment at the end of the original question). **Also, I don't know how to remove the circles**.

Comment: @Davood In your preamble, you must load the `tikz` package and the `cd` library or just `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`. The whole `tikzcd` environment can reside in a different file and can be `\input`ed.

Comment: @Davood The circles can be removed by removing `circle, draw` (and possibly more) from the `cells={nodes={…}}` entry. The `crossing over` key works by first drawing a fat white line and then the actual arrow, therefore it must come after the line that should be painted over. In your case, you should use `\ar[dd, crossing over]` from the `b_2` cell, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your generous and kind answers. Now I am able to create all of the six cubes described in the question. As you've guided I've loaded `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` and `\usetikzlibrary{cd}`, and after ignoring `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` everything was fine, and by using `\input`  everything was done.  Thanks for all.